# Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException' exception

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have this entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT_TASCK")
@Data
public class ReportTasck {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    @Column(name = "type")
    public String type;
    @Column(name = "status")
    public Integer status;
    @Column(name = "type")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportTasck", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Bill> bills;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BIIL")
@Data
public class Bill {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
    @Column(name = "neme")
    public String neme;
    @Column(name = "status")
    public Integer status;
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_TASCK_ID")
    public ReportTasck reportTasck;
}
```

then I tried fill it and save

```
ReportTasck reportTasck = new ReportTasck();
        reportTasck.setStatus(0);
        reportTasck.setType("standart");
        List<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BillDto billDto : all) {//640 items
           Bill bill = new Bill();
            bill.setStatus(0);
            bill.setNeme(billDto.getBill());
            bill.setReportTasck(reportTasck);
            bills.add(bill);
        }
        reportTasck.setBills(bills);
        reportTasckRepository.save(reportTasck);
```

but when start this line  `reportTasck.setBills(bills);` I get error in debbug mode Method threw `'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate entity.ReportTasck.toString()`

and when I tried save I get this error `Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException' exception.`

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]
```

I dont understand why I get this error and how fix

Comment: Post ddl of your tables.

Comment: @Column(name = "type")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportTasck", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Bill> bills;
Should it have "type" name

Comment: You are getting StackOverflowError likely because of recursion in your `toString()` method. Every bill refers to the ReportTask and it contains the same Bills which will recurse infinitely. Likely due to the autogenerated `toString()` from Lombok.

Comment: @Dominik Kunicki Thank you so much. I'm inconsiderate.

Comment: @ conscells I add @ToString(exclude="reportTasck") annotation and error missing. Why in lombok toString method generated so? It is bag?